# Is there an orthogonal coordinate system built around constant-eccentricity ellipses?

Tags: coordinate-systems

The [elliptic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system) for the plane, which transforms the coordinates $(\mu,\nu)$ to the cartesian $(x,y)$ via
\begin{align}
x&=a\cosh(\mu)\cos(\nu)\\
y&=a\sinh(\mu)\sin(\nu),
\end{align}
is a useful way to describe elliptical geometries in the plane (and, through its [oblate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_coordinates) and [prolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroidal_coordinates) extensions, in three-dimensional space). In this geometry, the surfaces of constant $\mu$ form a family of confocal ellipses of variable eccentricity, that start close to the interval between $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$, and approach circles as $\mu$ grows.

It was [recently suggested to me](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/electric-potential-of-a-spheroidal-gaussian?noredirect=1#comment765707_57260), as a possible resolution to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/electric-potential-of-a-spheroidal-gaussian), that it might be possible to build an orthogonal coordinate system for the plane whose surfaces of constant coordinate $\mu$ are also ellipses of a constant eccentricity and variable foci, i.e. such that 
$$
\mu=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}},
$$
with a coordinate $\nu$ built so its lines of constant $\nu$ are orthogonal to the constant-$\mu$ ellipses.

Is this possible? If not, why not? If it is, are there analytical expressions for $\nu$? How does the laplacian look like in this coordinate system?

Comment: One choice of $\nu$ is $a^2\log|x|-b^2\log|y|$.